# Security System Sensor Wiring Questions

Tags: electrical, security, low-voltage

I just disassembled my wired security system to hook my sensors to a konnected board to self manage through Smartthings. Inside the panel box cover is a listing of the zones.

Basement Door
Basement Motion
Back Motion
Front Motion

Amongst others that I am not concerned about. However there is no wire labled 'Back Motion'. There are wires for the other three. I presume that the back and front motion zones were merged somewhere in the house and they didn't fit the panel list. How WOD I check to confirm this? My best guess would be to apply power to the wire and then have someone trip each sensor and check the signal wires with a multimeter. Am I on the right track?

Comment: what do you mean by WOD?  Motion sensors require 24x7 power, how are they powered?

Comment: @Harper Sorry would. They were fully powered but since I dismantled the panel all I have are the labeled wire. Just trying to devise a little test before I integrate the wiring into my new setup.

Comment: Sounds like you're now trying to reverse engineer how power/signal works on these various sensors.  That's not our bailiwick, but it sounds like a natural for either electronics.stackexchange or iot.stackexchange.  However youd need to show the research you've thusfar done; no one will hand you an answer wrapped in a bow.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the wires behind each sensor.  You may find a double set of wires behind one of the sensors.  If not, disconnect all the wires from the panel and sensors, then short out two of the wires and see if the same two are shorted at the other sensor with a continuity tester, then test the wires at the panel as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. They used an unlabeled 6 wire cable for some reason and capped two of them and used the remaining four wires for the pair of back of the house sensors.